# Copy texlive from machine to machine

Tags: installing

I have texlive full installed on a machine. I want to copy it to another machine. On one machine, it is available on `/usr/share/texlive/`. I can copy this to other machine. Can I the list of all scripts or commands that I need to put in `/usr/bin` like `tex` or `latex` to make everything work properly on the second machine. Both machine have ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: That sound like a latex installed via Ubuntu repositories, as far as I remember all files are not stored in one single tree. Might be better to install up stream tl16 (which just froze and will never be updated again), that will end up with everything in a single tree, and you can easily copy this from machine to machine and just add the new latex to the from of your path (use at least the profile to make changes to paths or things started via menus cannot find them, and don't make softlinks into say `/usr/bin/` you'll just forget them later creating lots of havoc).

Comment: Could you not just install it new? WEhat is the purpose of copying it from one to another machine?